# Firebase debug mode is not uploading log event

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, analytics

Below logs are showing in console when I enable the debug mode for Firebase. Could not able to find the issue why it is not uploading.

```
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Uploading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/a
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, -1
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Do not schedule an upload task. Task already exists
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Canceling active timer
<FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Cancelling background upload task.
```

test log code below

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"Test"
                        parameters:@{
                                     @"name": @"Test",
                                     @"full_text": @"Test"
                                     }];
```

Comment: @VladPulichev please check updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am previously using firebase pod version **"3.2.1"**. I just **updated** my pod file to **'~>3.17.0'** and after that followed the debug guild mentioned in firebase documentation. Debug logs started show up on firebase portal.

documentation link : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Hope it help :)